# ImportError: cannot import name 'gTTS' on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, importerror, speech-to-text, gtts

I am trying to write a python script which can speak text. I wrote this simple code using gtts, which works on my macbook, but has import errors when I try to run it on Ubuntu 18.04

**st.py**

```
import os
mytext = "Python can speak!"
language = 'en'
myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False)
myobj.save("welcome.mp3")
os.system("mpg321 welcome.mp3")
```

I am using python3 to run it on ubuntu, and I have installed gtts using pip3, but it's not able to find gTTS. This is the error I am getting -

```
  File "connector.py", line 4, in <module>
    from gtts import gTTS 
ImportError: cannot import name 'gTTS'
```

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing gtts module and python3, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

- First make sure you are in the appropriate virtual environment if you are using one.
- Then try running `$ python3 -m pip install gTTS` without sudo
- If that is the command you already used to install gTTS, try running
  `pip list` to see if gTTS is listed there.
- Check to make sure that the `gtts` folder exists in `lib/python3.X/site-packages/`